# Diffeomorphic Regular surfaces

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, diffeomorphism

I came across the following question whilst preparing for an exam.

> Consider the map $f:\mathbb{R}^{3} \to \mathbb{R}$ given by the polynomial $f(x,y,z)=x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2}$. Let $s,t \neq 0$. Show that the regular surfaces $f^{-1}(t)$ and $f^{-1}(s)$ are diffeomorphic if and only if $t/s$ is positive.

I showed that $f^{-1}(a)$ is a regular surface if $a \neq 0$ using the Regular Value Theorem, but I'm not sure how to show the statement. For the *only if* direction I had in mind that given $t/s$ is positive we have $t,s>0$ or $t,s<0$ and then construct an explicit diffeomorphism, but I feel like there should be a better way to do this.

Comment: Can $a,t$ or $s$ be negative? What are those surfaces geometrically?

Comment: @kurtG. They can't be, so the level sets $f^{-1}(a)$ describe the sphere with radius $\sqrt{a}$. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic. And how to write a diffeomorphism?

Comment: You need to rescale the sphere for a fixed factor, which depends on $\frac t s$. Make some tries!